# Http Redirect with IIS 8.5

Tags: http, iis, host

In my IIS 8.5 i'm hosting a web site : https://Mysubdomain.domain.com/mywebsite

How can I redirect this url to : https://Mysubdomain.domain.com
is it possible by using http redirect iis feature?

I can't edit the actual binding to set a host name, because i'have more then 10 web applications under this binding.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you already fired up your favourite search engine?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use URL Rewrite where you can add a rule to match that folder and redirect to the root:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: Hi Carlos and thank you for the tip. I've already get url-rewrite 2.0. I think in my case i have to make rewrite instead of redirect. I'll look back if it work.